# Set 'Local Group Policy Editor' settings from code

Tags: c#, .net, cmd, group-policy

Some things are set through the `Local Group Policy Editor`.

Is there a way to set them in code? If not, is there a way through the command line (and therefore I can call *that* from code)?

Comment: It depends to the settings which you are setting in GPEdit...

Comment: @RezaAghaei You're saying there's no general command line command such as `LGPECommand "pathInLGPE" someAction`. Right? If so, that's a shame. It could have been useful.

Comment: There is. For example you can use [Group Policy PowerShell Cmdlets](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee461027.aspx) or [Import-GPO](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee461044.aspx) command. Also you can change settings using registry.

Comment: If my answer is helpful please mark it as answer for future programmers

Answer (score 1):

The only thing `Local Group Policy Editor` does is this: **it pushes/creates registry keys**. So what you actually want to do is create registry keys with your code (there is a API to do that).

First go to your Local Group Policy Editor make the change you want (manually) then refresh or open your Registry editor. After that click `control + f` (in Registry) to search for certain keys. Try to find the keys your LGPE created or changed in the Registry.

If you found the edited or created keys the rest is easy, you just have to make the same registry changes with your code.

Edit: I think there is some software that tracks the registry for changes. You can Google it.

Comment: This does not work like this. Most of these local group policy settings are located in a store and loaded temporarily in Windows Registry under certain keys. Creating directly just those Windows Registry keys will not have the same effect like when you modify them in gpedit.msc. Those settings must be added in this file "C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy\Machine\Registry.pol", then you can use "gpudate /force" and only then you will have them really applied.

Comment: I never faced a problem with my method. The changes seem to be permanent

Comment: It depends. Some registry keys work like you explained, some (most of them) don't. The Windows Registry is a temporary storage for local policy settings. If these settings are not stored in the policy, their corresponding Windows Registry (temporary storage) settings will be erased on next policy update.